# How to get Auth0 OAuth flow to return email claim in JWT token for swagger calls?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, jwt, swagger, auth0

The code below uses swagger to trigger an auth0 authentication form which then returns to swagger with an authenticated bearer token. The only problem is that the token does not include the email claim. The auth0 SDK returns a token with a user_id and an email claim. How do I include the email claim when I use OAuth flow?

Same question asked in forum

https://community.auth0.com/t/why-does-auth0-sdk-return-email-and-user-id-claim-but-not-the-oauth-flow/89735

Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using [...];

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build()
    .GetSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = config.Auth0.Domain;
            options.Audience = config.Auth0.Audiences.First();
            options.MetadataAddress = $"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            { 
                ValidAudiences = config.Auth0.Audiences,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options=>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Title",
        Version = "v1"
    });

    options.AddSecurityDefinition(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/authorize/?audience={config.Auth0.Audiences.First()}"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/oauth/token"),
                RefreshUrl = new Uri($"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/oauth/token"),
            }
        },
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    }); ;

    var reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme };
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement { { new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = reference }, new List<string>() } });
});

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.OAuthClientId(config.Auth0.ClientId);
        options.OAuthClientSecret(config.Auth0.ClientSecret);
    });
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

https://jwt.io/

The returned JWT token payload data only contains the 'sub' which is good but we also need the email for it to be useful.

```
{
  "iss": "https://instance.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|1234..........1234",
  "aud": "https://instance.us.auth0.com/api/v2/",
  "iat": 1234...1234,
  "exp": 1234...1234,
  "azp": "1234.....1234",
  "scope": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the "email" scope.

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
    {
        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/authorize/?audience={config.Auth0.Audiences.First()}"),
            TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/oauth/token"),
            RefreshUrl = new Uri($"https://{config.Auth0.Domain}/oauth/token"),
            
            // add this line
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "email", string.Empty }
            }
        }
    },
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
});
```

[Swagger - Add more scopes to Authorize button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248949/swagger-add-more-scopes-to-authorize-button)

Comment: I tried the `Scopes` parameter but the token does not seem to contain email still. I'm wondering if I'm not actually getting the correct token, or if auth0 is misconfigured. Maybe there is an initial token that has to be used to get more details. The documentation is confusing and auth0 support won't help unless you are part of the enterprise subscriptions ($20k a year).

Comment: Did the scope claim in token payload have email value `{ "scope": "email" }`?

Comment: When I add `Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "email", string.Empty } }` and I add   `options.OAuthScopes("email");` to swagger UI, the token added with the swagger calls comes back like this `"scope": ""`. The swagger UI suggests that the scope is added to the call, but the JWT token does not contain it. I believe I've seen the scopes added to the token before. I will try to get the scopes added to the token and see if the claim is added.

Comment: The scopes property of the token is empty in the token when I only provide email. If I provide "openid" "profile" and "email then the scope property shows all three. Even with the email scope listed in the token, the claim is still missing.

Comment: ```{
  "iss": "https://instance.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|1234....1234",
  "aud": [
    "https://instance.us.auth0.com/api/v2/",
    "https://instance.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1234
  "exp": 1234
  "azp": "some-code",
  "scope": "openid profile email"
}``` This is what the token looks like with the scopes added. I obviously replaces the sensative info

Comment: For a moment I forgot that those claims are actually going in the id_token and not in the access_token. Check the User ClaimsPrincipal inside a controller it might have the email claim.

Comment: Check this: https://community.auth0.com/t/add-email-to-initial-token/40307/5

Comment: I set up little test method to inspect the ClaimsPrinciple `[HttpGet(nameof(AIdentity))]
        public IActionResult AIdentity()
        {
            var user = HttpContext.User;
            return Ok(user);
        }`
The Claims associated are the same as the token. Interestingly there is this audience `/userinfo` that makes me think, can I query for the full user object?

Comment: This might help: https://community.auth0.com/t/i-cant-add-the-user-email-on-access-token/83958